# Advice on asynchronous programming... VB .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, asynchronous, thread-safety

I have a desktop application where users can select a number of rows displayed in a form (customs declarations actually) and send them via web service to get a response with the information of their current state, that needs to be updated in the database.

Since now this process was made synchronously. Get the first row, consume the web service, wait for the response, update the state in database and then move to the next row. But the number of rows processed each time is growing (4000-5000 at a time) and its taking a while to complete.

So what I did is parallelize the consumption of the web service for each row more or less like this:

```
'I can't parallelize the transactions with the database (business logic reasons), 
'so I use a queue for storing the responses as they arrive 
Private ResponseQueue as ConcurrentQueue(Of WebServiceResponseDataType)

Private NumberOfRowsToSend as Integer
Private CounterResponsesProcessed as Integer

Public Sub Send(ByVal dataTableRowsToSend As DataTable) 
  
    NumberOfRowsToSend = dataTableRowstoSend.Rows.Count()
    
    'I use a separate Thread to launch the method that will be updating the database 
    'as the queue is filled with responses
    Dim responseProcessorThread as Thread
    responseProcessorThread = New Thread(AddressOf ResponseProcessor)
    responseProcessorThread.Start()

    For Each row In dataTableRowsToSend.Rows
         Dim dataToSend() as Object
        'Do some previous validations and data formatting here.
        'I need to get some IDs from another tables in the database 
        'and increment them before consuming the web servcie. 
        'To avoid duplicate IDs I keep this part synchronous.
         
        'If the validations are passed I use the ThreadPool to queue the consumption of the WebService
         ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(New WaitCallback(AddressOf WebServiceConsumption)), dataToSend)
    Next
 
    'Wait for all responses to be processed
    'PS. I'm controlling if there is an exception during the webservice consumption,
    'generating a fake response in that case so the user can see what went wrong
     responseProcessorThread.Join()

End Sub

Private Sub ResponseProcessor()
        Dim WebServiceResponse As WebServiceResponseDataType

        While CounterResponsesProcessed < NumberOfRowsToSend 
             If ResponseQueue.Count > 0 AndAlso ResponseQueue.TryDequeue(WebServiceResponse) Then
                 UpdateRowStateInDataBase(WebServiceResponse)
                 CounterResponsesProcessed += 1
             End If
        End While
End Sub

Private Sub WebServiceConsumption (ByVal dataToSend() as Object)
     'This function consumes the web service and waits for the response. 
     'When the response arrives it goes to the queue:
      ResponseQueue.Enqueue(responseData)
End Sub
```

With this code the process is much faster since I don't have to wait for the response of the previous row to start with the next one.

But I'm not used to parallel programming and I'm not sure if this is a good approach or if I did something considered bad practice.

I.e. I dont feel comfortable using a counter to control when all the responses are updated in the database to know when the process is finished. Also after writing this code I have been reading that I should avoid using Threads directly and use Tasks instead.

Comment: What I would suggest as the best option is to just adapt your original code to use either `Parallel.For` in place of a `For` loop or `Parallel.ForEach` in place of a `For Each` loop. That will keep the changes to a minimum.

Comment: The alternative would be to use `Async`/`Await`. You can then call an asynchronous method multiple times and place the `Tasks` it returns into an array or collection. You can then await a call to `Task.WhenAll` to wait until all the `Tasks` have completed. This option will require more changes to the code but the advantage is that, by using `Await`, you can wait for all the work to complete without freezing the UI. What you're doing and my previous suggestion will both block and thus freeze the UI. If that's not an issue for whatever reason, I'd stick with less change.

Comment: Another thing to check on, does the web service have to facility to take batches of records in a single request?  If not might seem like a realistic request to enable that

Comment: @jmcilhinney I don't want to parallelize the code previous to the web service call since I need to get some IDs from another tables and increment them to prepare the data for each row (I will edit the OP to clarify that). I'm not sure if I could get repeated IDs if I parallelize that (I.e. 2 rows getting the same ID because the second one got the ID before the first one had time to increment it).
The UI doesn't need to be responsive while this process is running, so that's ok.

Comment: @Hursey I suggested it to the web service's devs, but if they enable that wont be in the short term :(

Comment: I would suggest that @jmcilhinney's comment is the correct answer to this question.  If your processing is IO bound then use `Async` / `Await`.  Using Async / Await will not parallelise the code before the `Async` calls.  It won't actually parallelise anything as parallelism != synchronicity.